# Dataflow use HBaseResultCoder when setting coder

Tags: hbase, google-cloud-dataflow, encoder

I have a dataflow job that scans two bigtables and then joins the `Result` of the scan by the row key.

I am trying to set the coder to HbaseResultCoder but I keep getting an error that its not the correct type

```
PCollection<KV<String, KV<Result, Result>>> rowsJoined = JoinerUtils.leftJoin(oldBtScan, newBtScan)
    .setCoder(KvCoder.of(StringUtf8Coder.of(), KvCoder.of(HBaseResultCoder.getInstance(), HBaseResultCoder.getInstance())));
```

Error is `reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) K exist so that HBaseResultCoder conforms to Coder<K>`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any documentation about **JoinerUtils.leftJoin** which I presume might be the cause of the error. Why don't you take advantage of Dataflow escalation capabilities and use the [Bigtable connector](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/hbase-dataflow-java?hl=en#reading)? With it you can read the Big Tables you want to combine in different *PCollections*, then use the **letfOuterJoin** of Apache Beam to combine them. Be aware that both PCollection must be in the form [leftOuterJoin(PCollection> leftCollection, PCollection> rightCollection, V2 nullValue)](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.1.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/joinlibrary/Join.html).

Hope you find this workaround helpful.